# (L'Étranger de Camus) "Il" in "Il les laissait seulement veiller"

Tags: pronoms, antécédent

The question is on *Il* as highlighted below.

> Ensuite il [le directeur de L’asile de vieillards] m’a dit qu’il assisterait à l’enterrement et je l’ai remercié. Il s’est assis derrière son bureau, il a croisé ses petites jambes. Il m’a averti que moi et lui serions seuls, avec l’infirmière de service. En principe, les pensionnaires ne devaient pas assister aux enterrements. **Il** les laissait seulement veiller : « C’est une question d’humanité », a-t-il remarqué. Mais en l’espèce, il avait accordé l’autorisation de suivre le convoi à un vieil ami de maman : « Thomas Pérez. »

**Question**

Does *Il* refer to *le directeur* or *le principe*?  Or is it unclear?

(I don't think the question is critical to understanding the conversation.  I imagine the answer is that it's unclear.  I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some cue available only to a native speaker definitely telling him that it was *le directeur* or *le principe*.  Thanks.)

Comment: That's a lot of questions about L'Étranger :-) **Il** refers to the director, since "en principe" is an expression ; it somehow loses its noun status to become an adverb, just as "en fait" ou "en général" do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Il* refers to *le directeur*. *Principe* used with the expression *en principe* works like an adverb (it would mean "generally" or "usually"), and you will never refer to it with a pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear *il* refers to *le directeur*.
That same *il* is repeated a lot of times. The whole paragraph gives a impression that the narrator doesn't like that *il*.